# convert number to String and separated with dot

Tags: java, format, decimal

I want convert number to String and separated with dot like 10000000 to 10.000.000 in java
how it possible

this is work but I  looking for better solution

```
int number  = 10000000;

NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
            
System.out.println(format.format(number).replace(",","."));
```

Comment: `Locale.GERMAN` should use the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
return decimalFormat.format(number);
```